# Is it ok to use COUNT queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it OK to use the **number of rows** in result returned by query (`COUNT()` function in MySQL) for any checks and so on?
For example if I want to check how many posts have the user made today to check if he can create another (in another words, have the user reached his daily limit), is it a good practice to just send a query like this

```
SELECT COUNT(post_text) FROM posts WHERE (date_published = CURDATE() AND userId = 115);
```

or is there a better approach. I faced this a couple of times (I don't write database logic often) and it always kinda confused me if I get this wrong or not. So hope you will just clarify this for me once and for all, thanks.

Comment: If you want to count the number of rows, then `COUNT()` is the right function.  Why would you not use it?

Comment: So I want to check if user has reached his limit and the implementation seems to be to just `COUNT` the rows, maybe there is nothing wrong, but I'm just not sure

Comment: You can use `COUNT()` just fine on the example topic that you provided.

Comment: Your current query makes no reference to the user. You may need to amend your where condition appropriately.

Comment: Yeah, the query has nothing to do with my project, but I will fix it anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user has daily limits, then you probably want to do this check in the database.

In that case, you would implement this restriction using a *trigger* rather than at the application level.  This ensures that the restriction is always applied, regardless of competing threads, table locks, or who is doing the update.

If you do want to implement the restriction at the application level, then you would use a query, presumably with `count()`.  I would expect the query to include the user id:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM posts p
WHERE p.date_published = CURDATE() AND p.user_id = ?;
```

Comment: Yeah, now I see, so that was actually my question (maybe the name is confusing, but still), I wanted to know what is the better way to specify this kind of limits, and _triggers_ seems to be better, so thanks for clarifying.